# How to set splash screen using Phonegap 3.x?

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap-desktop-app

How to setup splash screen in phonegap 3.x? I am using phonegap desktop and phonegap build. I am not using cli.

I have create a project via phonegap desktop app. So it is having all splashscreen images with all size for all platform.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

- Create Splash Screen with different resolution for your platform
- Create Cordova / Phonegap Projects
- Add Your Platform (Android / iOS / Windows)
- Install Splash Screen Plugin (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen)
- Open your config.xml file & Made Changes like

  ```
   <platform name="android">
   <splash src="res/hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
   <splash src="res/ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
   <splash src="res/mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
   <splash src="res/xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
   </platform>
  ```

& add

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
```

For more https://codesundar.com/setup-icon-splash-screen-for-phonegap-or-cordova-based-apps/

Comment: when i create phonegap desktop proejct it create config.xml 
but its not working